# AFNetworking was built without full bitcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am getting error "AFNetworking was built without full bitcode" when i enable bitcode in a project.
There is a [open issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4348) also there.

If anyone have solve the issue please help me.

AFNetworking version : 3.2.1

Detailed error : "ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceSDK-hkwcndktudaxkjebecaqimswckgp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceSDK-hkwcndktudaxkjebecaqimswckgp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking' for architecture armv7"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so i fixed the issue by adding following in podfile

```
    post_install do |installer|
         installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
             target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                 config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'bitcode'
                 config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
             end
         end
     end
```

May be it will help others.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it does help. a lot. Thank you so much!